# Dimensioning inodes count when creating a filesystem

Tags: linux, storage

I am trying to understand when and how to go from the default inode count when creating an ext4 filesystem.

I will reformat a 1 TB SSD, with an ext4 filesystem. The 1 TB SSD will be mounted to a folder on a 512 GB SSD on a centos 7.9 server.

Must I consider how many files I expect to have to be solely created on the 1 TB SSD ?

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Unless you have some kind of extremely special need (and if you don't know for sure that you do AND why, you almost certainly don't), you can and should just use the defaults when creating an ext4 filesystem.   In short: don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks @cas Much appreciated